# Javascript merge the values of 4 arrays into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have 4 arrays of the following format

```
arr1 = ['Hello', 'World', 'Hi']
arr2 = ['1', '2', '3']
arr3 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
arr4 = ['10', '20', '30']
```

I am trying to add each value at index[i] to a new object, the object looks like this

```
obj = {
 title: '',
 score: '',
 description: '',
 value: '',
}
```

For each indexed value in the array I would like to push it to a new instance of the obj object so I can end up with this

```
objects = [
 {
  title: 'Hello',
  score: '1',
  description: 'foo',
  value: '10',
 },
 {
  title: 'World',
  score: '2',
  description: 'bar',
  value: '20',
 },
 {
  title: 'Hi',
  score: '3',
  description: 'foobar',
  value: '30',
 }
]
```

So far I have been trying something like

```
objects = []
arr1.forEach((key, i) => objects[key] = arr2[i])
```

But that is assigning them as arr1val : arr2val

I will ultimately be setting this to state in my react app and passing it to another component as props to render on the page. The data is coming in from 3 different APIs, I am doing this to try and standardise the data received from each API so my component can use the data to render an articles list and user can switch between feeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map by the index of element across all arrays, also use `map` not `forEach`:

```
const objects = arr1.map((element, index) => (
 {title: element, score: arr2[index], description: arr3[index], value: arr4[index]}
))
```

Live demo is below:

```js
const arr1 = ['Hello', 'World', 'Hi']
const  arr2 = ['1', '2', '3']
const arr3 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
const arr4 = ['10', '20', '30']

const objects = arr1.map((element, index) => (
 {title: element, score: arr2[index], description: arr3[index], value: arr4[index]}
))

console.log(objects)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much this works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This code also works:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = {};
    arr[i].title = arr1[i];
    arr[i].score = arr2[i];
    arr[i].description = arr3[i];
    arr[i].value = arr4[i];
}
```

Comment: I prefer a good old `for` loop indeed. No need to bring out the big guns of fake functional programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an array of arrays and another array for the keys. This allows an arbitrary count of arrays and keys to use for transforming the data into an array of objects with hte wanted properties.

```js
var array1 = ['Hello', 'World', 'Hi'],
    array2 = ['1', '2', '3'],
    array3 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'],
    array4 = ['10', '20', '30'],
    keys = ['title', 'score', 'description', 'value'],
    result = [array1, array2, array3, array4].reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (v, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || {};
            r[j][keys[i]] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think that wasn't the expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to type the property names twice,
you could do like this:

```
const descriptor = {
  title: arr1,
  score: arr2,
  description: arr3,
  value: arr4
};

const objects = arr1.map((tmp, i) => {
  var o = {};
  Object.keys(descriptor).forEach(name => o[name] = descriptor[name][i]);
  return o;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A reducer method would be in place I suppose

```js
const arr1 = ['Hello', 'World', 'Hi', 'Hello2', 'World2', 'Hi2'];
const arr2 = ['1', '2', '3', '11', '22', '33'];
const arr3 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'sea', 'shell', 'sea weed'];
const arr4 = ['10', '20', '30', '100', '200', '300'];

const arrays2Objects = arr1.reduce( (obj, next, i) =>  
  obj.concat({title: next, score: arr2[i], description: arr3[i], value: arr4[i]}),
  []
);

console.log(arrays2Objects);
```